# Kubernetes 1.11 priority and preemption do not work

Tags: kubernetes, preemption

I followed the following instruction on `Kubernetes 1.11` but priority and preemption do not work.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#how-to-use-priority-and-preemption

I create 2 pods one `high-priority` (with 100000), another `lower priority` (0).
I run the low-priority pod to occupy all resources of a single node.
While the low-priority pod is running, I submitted the high-priority pod but the scheduler does not preempt the low-priority.

I tried another experiment to check whether priority works in queueing the pods. However, it does not order the pods in the queue based on priority values.

Is anyone having the same problem? 
Do I need to do anything else to enable this feature on `Kubernetes 1.11`?

Comment: can you share the configuration of the pods and share steps you've performed? Did you add the priority to the existing deployment or you had those options enabled with your deployment?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/9499 for your answer.

In short, there is a issue with pod priority and preemption in the kubernetes version 1.11. The issue has already been identified and a fix has been pushed. However, the fix will be available in 1.11.1, which I believe is still not up.

However, if you build the latest codebase from kuberenetes and deploy, it will work, as posted in the above github link

PS: I filed the issue in the github.